# make height responsive amp-list

Tags: amp-html

I'm trying to make the height of amp-list responsive

```
<amp-list width="100" height="1980" [height]="660 * page.items.posts.length" layout="responsive" src="/get_posts/" [src]="'/get_posts?page=' + page" binding="no" reset-on-refresh single-item> 
  <template type="amp-mustache">
    {{#posts}}
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      Post
      </div>
    {{/posts}}
  </template>
</amp-list>
```

as you see the height changes every time when I get new posts. the problem is it's working well on desktop but on mobile, I see only the first three posts because the height is small.
on the desktop, I have a large width so I can get 3 columns by line but on mobile, I can get only one column by line that's why I need more height, is there something that can fix this problem?

Comment: have you considered @media variations?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Answer (score 2):

You can use Media attribute over amp elements, refer amp page -

https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/control_layout/

example -

```
<amp-img
    media="(min-width: 650px)"
    src="wide.jpg"
    width="527"
    height="355"
    layout="responsive">
</amp-img>

<amp-img
    media="(max-width: 640px)"
    src="small.jpg"
    width="527"
    height="355"
    layout="responsive">
</amp-img>
```

Above 2 elemts will display based on media attribute condition written in each of them. First will display when display size min-width: 650px ].

Comment: but the problem is from the amp-list

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `layout="fill"` instead of responsive or fixed-height and remove height attribute. Also for your `amp-list` element set `min-height` to height of 1st element and position to relative in your CSS e.g:

AMP-HTML:

```
<amp-list layout="fill" binding="no" load-more="auto" single-item reset-on-refresh>
```

CSS:

```
amp-list {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

That solution works for me, but it violates the main idea of AMP (content jumps)